# Passing auto increment id to second query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Currently I've got two queries, where the first one has an auto increment id. I would like to pass this id to my second query. But can't figure out how to do this. I've used 'mysqli_insert_id', but it returned in to the database.

This is my code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO klanten (bedrijfsnaam) VALUES ('Some name')";
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
second_query = "INSERT INTO klantnotitie (login_id) VALUES ('" . $last_id . "')";
```

To avoid confusion: I want to insert to id of the first query into another table where it will just be an integer.

Hope someone can help me out!

Comment: You're not executing either of the queries

Comment: and please use parameterized statements, so you don't have to worry about data types in your queries. i'm 100% certain an automatically incremented ID is **not** a string.

Comment: @Daan I am executing them, but I did only show the query part of the code here.

Comment: @Bart Please post the full code then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like that

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO klanten (bedrijfsnaam) VALUES ('Some name')";
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $second_query = "INSERT INTO klantnotitie (login_id) VALUES ('" . $last_id . "')";
    mysqli_query($con, $second_query);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Indeed had execute the first query before defining the second one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**It will work in this way**

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE myCity LIKE City");

$query = "INSERT INTO klanten (bedrijfsnaam) VALUES ('Some name')";
mysqli_query($link, $query);

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", mysqli_insert_id($link));
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);

second_query = "INSERT INTO klantnotitie (login_id) VALUES ('" . $last_id . "')";
mysqli_query($link, $second_query);


/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming You are executing your queries,

1. You can use Mysql's function: [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Example:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

2. You can use PHP's function [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Example:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
//.. some code
$query = "INSERT INTO klanten (bedrijfsnaam) VALUES ('Some name')";
mysqli_query($link, $query);
printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", mysqli_insert_id($link));
```